# Is there a way to check which file that has been loaded into a UIImage object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have three files : *background~ipad.png, background@2x~iphone.png & background~iphone.png*

When I set the background image I use:

`[self.background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];`

Is there any way for me to verify that *background@2x~iphone.png* is the file being loaded when I run the retina screen simulator? Because it looks (ocularly) like it's *background~iphone.png* that's being loaded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try temporarily changing the content of the images to verify that the correct image gets loaded. For example make the background~ipad.png solid blue and the background~iphone.png solid green. That way you will see if the right one is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the size of the image before you set it:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];

NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(backgroundImage.size);

[self.background setImage:backgroundImage];
```

Also, I would remove ~iphone extension, just use background and background@2x, then either use ~ipad or use the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() macro to detect iPad and set a different image altogether.

Comment: Thanks, but why is it better to detect platform programmatically? 
Apple themselves advocates using the file name extensions. http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html

Comment: You're right, in which case I take that back. I usually have all my iPad images named differently, which I don't need to do, it seems. Thanks.